# Proof that inhomogeneous solution is independent of a coordinate in Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, poissons-equation

Suppose we have this Poisson equation 
$$
\nabla^{2}\phi(x,y,z)=\rho(x,y).
$$
A solution would be of the form 
$$
\phi=\phi_0(x,y,z)+\phi_1(x,y)
$$ 
where $\phi_0(x,y,z)$ is solution of the Laplace equation 
$\nabla^{2}\phi(x,y,z)=0$.

How can we prove that $\phi_1(x,y)$ is independent of the coordinate $z$ ?

Comment: You can't say $\phi_{1}$ is independent of $z$, it just means $(\phi_{1})_{zz} = 0$ i.e $\phi_{1} = Az + B$ for come constants $A, B$.

Comment: But how can we know that this solution is unique?

Comment: Uniqueness of which solution, $\phi_{0}$, $\phi_{1}$ or both?

Comment: The solution $\phi_1$.  Maybe boundary condition will impose that the solution is unique?

Comment: Uniqueness comes from boundary conditions. You need $6$ boundary conditions all together, $2$ for $x$ direction, $2$ for $y$ direction, $2$ for $z$ direction.

Comment: i see . ok thanks